# Implementing Feature Managment in AspNetBoilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to figure out the 'appropriate' way to implement Feature Management in aspnetboilerplate ABP/(actually AspNetZero)

Here is my specific business situation:  I want to limit through Features/Editions, the number of Organizational Units a tenant is able to create.

Im not sure where this should be implemented.  In the Application layer?  My research in the code, for example ABPZero implements a IUserPolicy/UserPolicy to manage users creation.  This is implemented in the Core project.  But Im embarassed to say that I can't find and OrganizationUnit.cs class in order to implement this correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

--Dave